# How to add an SSL certificate to an azure website using powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, ssl, certificate

I am working on automatic deployment + azure.  I'm at the point where i'm adding an ssl cert to the website. Does anyone know how to use PowerShell to upload an SSL certificate to a website using the PowerShell command (Add - Get - Set based commands)?  I'm able to add a certificate to a cloud service using ...

```
New-AzureService $Program -Location 'East US'
Add-AzureCertificate -Password Cert123! -ServiceName $Program -CertToDeploy $CertLocation
```

but I have no idea how to add it to an azure website.

Thanks

edit: I've found a way using the following command, but i'm not wanting to install additional libraries on my production deployment machine.

```
azure site cert add -k Cert123! $CertLocation $Program
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the Azure PowerShell cmdlets do not offer this capability at the moment that I could find.  As you point out the Cross Platform Command Line tool does.  Since you don't want to add the XPlat-CLI tool to your deployment machines you can use what the XPlat-CLI tool does under the hood: a direct call against the REST api for web site management.

Note you'll need to figure out what webspace the site resides in, etc. You can use the Invoke-WebRequest to make this call so that you can verify you get that 200 response back.  Or you could use the Invoke-RESTMethod as well, but that would only return an XML document (the contents of the response).  The Invoke-WebRequest provides you a little more control and access to the full response object.

The [Microsoft Azure Management Libraries](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2014/04/wamlmaml/) (which the PowerShell cmdlets sit on top of) has a Web Site Management piece to it.  One of the operations is an update to a site and that includes a WebSiteUpdateParameters object with a SSLCertificates property.  You may check into that as well, though I've not done this myself.

Comment: Your details led me to http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/17/using-the-windows-azure-rest-apis-with-powershell.aspx which explains the implementation of the Azure Rest API.  This in my opinion is better (at this time) than either NPM and PowerShell commands until they are finished.

Comment: Now I don't see this ability even in cli tool

Comment: I'm looking at the cli source to see where this 'site cert add' command is, because I've found out how to set the certificate (you'll need the fingerprint) but not where to upload the certificate. Also, what are "web spaces"?

Answer (score 5):

Using the newly released Azure PowerShell v. 1.1.0, you can use the following command to upload a certificate to your website

```
New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName myresourcegroup -WebAppName mytestapp -CertificateFilePath PathToPfxFile -CertificatePassword PlainTextPwd -Name www.contoso.com
```

More information is in the following article
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-app-powerhell-ssl-binding/

Comment: In my case, I am not binding the certificate to SSL operations, I need it for data encryption.  The Portal seems to deny any certificate that isn't SSL enabled, and the command above also seems to assume SSL is the reason I'm uploading the cert. Uploading a cert and assigning a cert to be used for IIS/SSL seem like separate needs to me... any ideas?

Comment: In case someone needs an update link to docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#azure-powershell