# What is a pfxblob

Tags: c#, certificate, pfx

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727287/how-to-add-a-certificate-to-an-azure-rm-website-with-powershell) question the other day.

Part of the solution required a `base64binary of the pfxblob` to put into the Azure Template, to pass to Azure via Powershell.

I ultimately found I could get a pfxblob by running a different Azure command, the [source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/f803b991daa7eeeea1217238ab071c8d83de34be/src/ResourceManager/Network/Commands.Network/ApplicationGateway/SslCertificate/AzureApplicationGatewaySslCertificateBase.cs) of which contained a chunk of c# that did what I needed it to.

Namely -

```
Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, Password));)
```

I'm mostly able to pick that apart and vaguely get what it is doing, at least enough to fix my immediate problem at the time. But I never did work out what a pfxblob actually is. And on the run up finding that solution, I couldn't find anything that described what it was.

So I thought one of you lot must...

Comment: Check this blog post [here](http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2) explaining what a pfx file is. With that in mind , a pfxblob is a binary file which contains the public and private stuff of the certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PFX files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867088.aspx) contain encrypted private keys, certificates, and potentially other secret information.

Generally, a PFX BLOB is a binary representation of a PFX store. More [precisely](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a PFX BLOB is a `CRYPT_DATA_BLOB` structure. The `CRYPT_DATA_BLOB` is specified in the [typedef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `_CRYPTOAPI_BLOB`.

The _CRYPTOAPI_BLOB contains an arbitrary array of bytes. Its struct consists of `DWORD cbData`, which is A DWORD variable that contains the count, in bytes, of data; and `BYTE  *pbData', which contains A pointer to the data buffer.

Therefore, a PFX BLOB contains the binary content of a PFX store, plus the length of the store.

It is worth reading this page for further information: [PKCS #12 File Types: Portable Protected Keys in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867088.aspx)

Major APIs that use the PFX BLOB are these:

- [PFXIsPFXBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [PFXImportCertStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Is a pfxblob a purely MS concept? does it have an equivalent in other environments?

Comment: @MichaelB PFX is a Microsoft-invented technology. https://cryptome.org/jya/pg-get-MSkey.htm , but other platforms use the PFX BLOB. For instance, see this Java documentation: http://lxr.mozilla.org/security/source/security/jss/org/mozilla/jss/pkcs12/PFX.java