# Using Set-AzureRmResource - JSON Powershell Syntax?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to use "Set-AzureRmResource" to configure WebApp configuration in Azure.

I have a piece of code here which works to set "alwaysOn = True" :

```
$PropertiesObject = @{
"alwaysOn" = $true;
}
Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $SiteName/web -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
### in this case "alwaysOn' sits within "properties": {.
```

I now want to set another property however this one is nested. eg:

```
"azureBlobStorage": {
"sasUrl": null,
"retentionInDays": null,
"enabled": false
}
### in this case I want to set SasUrl which sits within "properties"{ AzureBlobStorage {
```

I'm lost on syntax to use to set properties which are nested like this.

Sorry if my terminology is not right, powershell and Json are pretty new to me, I'm learning as I go.

The Azure documentation simply states:

```
# SET web
$PropertiesObject = @{
#Property = value;
}
```

#

```
"properties": {
"httpLogs": {
  "fileSystem": {
    "retentionInMb": 35,
    "retentionInDays": null,
    "enabled": false
  },
  "azureBlobStorage": {
    "sasUrl": null,
    "retentionInDays": null,
    "enabled": false
  }
},
```

Comment: Please also note that `azureBlobStorage` is under `$SiteName/logs` and not `$SiteName/web`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone else sees this and can't figure it out; I got this working with Hashtables in a simpler method rather than creating inner objects. Here's an example of turning off FileSystem logging for the ApplicationLogs:

```
$propertiesObject = [ordered] @{
                            'applicationLogs' = @{
                                'fileSystem' = @{
                                    'level' = 'Off'
                                 }   
                            }
                        }
Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $propertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "$($webAppName)/logs" -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

You can do the same thing for the original OP request of setting the HttpLogs sasUrl property:

```
$propertiesObject = [ordered] @{
                            'httpLogs' = @{
                                'azureBlobStorage' = @{
                                    "sasUrl": "SASURL"
                                 }   
                            }
                        }
Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $propertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "$($webAppName)/logs" -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

Comment: - thanks for posting your update, this is the much easier and simpler method. I can see now it's all in the formatting of the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while too!

I have got an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727287) that covers it. You basically have to create the inner object, and then add that object to the outer property.

So if you want something like

```
{
"Property":  [
        {
            "prop2":  1,
            "prop1":  "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

You would use

```
$InnerPropertiesObject = @{
        prop1 = "string"
        prop2 = 1
      }
$PropertiesObject = @{
    "Property" = [Object[]]$InnerPropertiesObject 
}
```

and then use

```
New-AzureRmResource -Name $ResourceName `
                -Location $ResourceLocation `
                -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject `
                -ResourceGroupName examplecomRG `
                -ResourceType $resourceType `
                -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for the response.

It's a little bit over my head as I don't understand hash tables yet but it gives me something to read and learn.

Reading through the JSON template I believe I need to go another level deep to set the correct value, so I can follow your example and nest it further. eg.:  "properties": { "httpLogs": {  "azureBlobStorage"

Comment: @James it was figuring out how to do this that got me understanding hashtables! (crazy things that they are!) - at least a little better anyway - but yes, you should be able to further nest them