# New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding - The specified network password is not correct

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

I'm following [How to add a certificate to an Azure RM website with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727287/how-to-add-a-certificate-to-an-azure-rm-website-with-powershell) and trying to add a certificate with the following Powershell

```
New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName MyResource -WebAppName mysite -Name www.contoso.com -CertificateFilePath "C:\Secure\mycert.pfx" -CertificatePassword plaintextPassword
```

But it's returning with

```
New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding : The specified network password is not correct.
```

However, if I use the Azure portal I can add the certificate successfully from the pfx file, so the password is definitely correct.

Answer (score 1):

> New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding : The specified network password is not correct.

As far as I know, [the certificate will be added via REST](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scicoria/2015/01/31/azure-resource-manager-adding-and-assigning-certificates-to-a-website/) when we execute **New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding** cmdlet. And I could see this request details if I specify **-Debug** parameter for New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding cmdlet.

[image]

And if I provide an incorrect value for -CertificatePassword, It returns the same error.

[image]

So please check the CertificatePassword again to make sure you provide the same value (the value of Certificate password input on Azure portal) for New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is dated. However for anyone else that runs into the issue try the following.

-CertificatePassword "PlainTextPassword"

Don't forget to add the quotes.

To take it a step further, for the sake of security, you can pass in your certificate password via keyvault.

```
$vaultname = "keyvault"
$secrectname = "keyvaultsecret"
$resourcegroup = "resourcegroupname"
$webappname = "webappname"
$hostname = "example.com"

$secretsecurestring = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret - 
VaultName $vaultname -Name $secretname
$pfxpass = $secretsecurestring.SecretValueText

New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName 
$resourcegroup -WebAppName $webappname - 
CertificateFilePath C:\Certificate.pfx - 
CertificatePassword $pfxpass -Name $hostname
```