# AzureRm Add-AzureCertificate equivalent in Az

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-rm, az

Ahead of the deprecation of the AzureRM powershell cmdlets later this year I am updating some of our infrastructure scripts to use the Az powershell cmdlets rather than AzureRM.

One of our scripts uploads SSL certificates to Azure `Cloud Service(Classic)` resources using [`Add-AzureCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/add-azurecertificate?view=azuresmps-4.0.0):

`Add-AzCertificate -ServiceName $serviceName -CertToDeploy $certObject`

where `$certObject` is a `X509Certificate2` object.

What is the equivalent cmdlet in the Az module?  `Add-AzCertificate` does not exist.

On the [Cloud Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-certs-create) documentation page where it details [configuring SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate-portal), only certificate upload via the Azure portal is shown.

Comment: Try running `Get-Command -Name Add-Az*Certificate -Module Az.*` in Powershell and see what modules are available?

Comment: Also is this for SSL binding for a Azure web app? If so you could use `New-AzWebAppSSLBinding`, which can take a `.pfx` certificate as input. I found this with `Get-Command -Name *SSL* -Module Az.*`.

Comment: @RoadRunner This is about Azure Cloud Services which I don't believe is supported in the new Azure Powershell Cmdlets (which is a shame considering there are so many organizations that still use Cloud Services).

Comment: Long shot idea: call `Enable-AzureRmAlias` and try calling the old Cmdlet - if it works without the "old" powershell modules, you know that it should exist

Comment: Unfortunately, after `Enable-AzureRmAlias`, `Add-AzureCertificate` appears to be broken , throwing a `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`: ComputeManagementClient requires a
                        WebRequestHandler in its HTTP pipeline to work with client certificates.  I have been unable to find any information on this error or how to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment from @Alex AIT, before call the AzureRM commands, you can run [Enable-AzureRmAlias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/enable-azurermalias?view=azps-3.6.1) cmdlet which enables a compatibility mode through aliases, to allow you to use **existing scripts** with minimal modification while working towards a full migration to **Az**. For more information, you could refer to [Migrate existing scripts to Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.6.1#migrate-existing-scripts-to-az).

Also, to call Azure Cloud Service(Classic) resources, you still need Azure modules. View this example- [Az / AzureRM / Legacy Azure Powershell Conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380450/az-azurerm-legacy-azure-powershell-conflicts).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; unfortunately this still appears to be broken.  `Add-AzureCertificate` throws  a `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`: ComputeManagementClient requires a WebRequestHandler in its HTTP pipeline to work with client certificates.  I have so far been unable to find any information on this error or how to get things working.

Comment: not sure, Could you try the 3 examples [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-powershell/blob/master/azuresmps-4.0.0/Azure/Add-AzureCertificate.md#example-3-upload-a-certificate-object)? Are there the same error? Or have a try with `New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066463/how-to-add-an-ssl-certificate-to-an-azure-website-using-powershell